# My Javascript/jQuery gallery only works on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost, image-gallery

My Javascript/jQuery gallery only works on localhost. As soon as I try to view the same gallery on my server hosted version of my site it does show the pictures and sections of the pictures, but it is not lined up with eachother like the localhost version site gallery is.

[Good Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I25sh.png)

[Wrong Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmzqH.png)

Here is my page code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bvstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/plugins.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/recepten.css">


    <title>Bani - Recepten</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--banner en logo-->
<div id="banner-wrapper">
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"><img  class="banner" src="images/banner2.png" style="width: 1777px">
</div>

<!--Begin navbar-->
<div class="navigatiebar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light "> <!--Navigatie balk die uitbreid wanneer het scherm medium of groter is. achtergrond is wit met een licht thema. Navigatiebalk zit vast aan de bovenkant van het scherm.-->

    <!--Toggler/collapsible Button-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"><!--navigatieknopje als het scherm kleiner is dan medium.-->
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> <!--3 streepjes onder elkaar.-->
    </button>

    <!--Navbar links-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="shop.php">Producten</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="recepten.php">Recepten
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav><!--Einde navbar-->
</div>

<!--Achtergrond en sfeer-->
<img src="images/recepten_banner.jpg" style="border-style: solid none solid none; border-width: 5px; border-color: yellow">


<!--Content-->


<!--Recepten galerij-->

<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
    <div class="box">
        <h2 class="section-title pull-left">Recepten</h2>
        <div id="filters-container" class="cbp-l-filters-alignRight pull-right">
            <div data-filter="*" class="cbp-filter-item-custom btn cbp-filter-item-custom-active"> Alles
                <div class="cbp-filter-counter">12</div>
            </div>
            <div data-filter=".voorgerecht" class="cbp-filter-item-custom btn"> Voorgerecht
                <div class="cbp-filter-counter">3</div>
            </div>
            <div data-filter=".hoofdgerecht" class="cbp-filter-item-custom btn"> Hoofdgerecht
                <div class="cbp-filter-counter">3</div>
            </div>
            <div data-filter=".nagerecht" class="cbp-filter-item-custom btn"> Nagerecht
                <div class="cbp-filter-counter">3</div>
            </div>
            <div data-filter=".tussendoortje" class="cbp-filter-item-custom btn"> Tussendoortje
                <div class="cbp-filter-counter">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div id="grid-container" class="cbp-l-grid-masonry cbp cbp-chrome cbp-caption-fadeIn cbp-animation-quicksand cbp-ready cbp-cols-3" style="height: 702px;">
            <ul class="cbp-wrapper">
                <li class="cbp-item frame voorgerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/avocadosoep.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/nachosoep.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Avocadosoep met nacho's</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame voorgerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(360px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a  href="recepten/erwtensoep.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/erwtensoep.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Erwtensoep</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame hoofdgerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(720px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/spaghetti.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/pasta_gehaktbal.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Spaghetti met gehaktballetjes</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame hoofdgerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(0px, 178px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/wokschotel.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/wokschotel.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Thaise wokschotel met pittige biefstukreepjes</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame hoofdgerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(360px, 178px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a  href="recepten/bamisoep.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/bamisoep.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Bamisoep</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame tussendoortje" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(360px, 178px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/avocadotosti.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/avocado.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Avocado-tosti</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame nagerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(0px, 354px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/frambozencake.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/framboos.png" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Chocolade-frambozenijscake</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame nagerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(360px, 356px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a  href="recepten/cheesecake.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/cheesecake.png" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Cheesecake met dadels</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame tussendoortje" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(360px, 178px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a  href="recepten/snackpeper.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/snackpeper.png" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Snackpeper</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame nagerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(720px, 356px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/nutella.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/nutella.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Nutella-mascarponetaart</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame nagerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(360px, 178px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a  href="recepten/regenboog.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/regenboog.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Regenboogtoetje</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame voorgerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(0px, 531px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/maaltijdsalade.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/salade.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Maaltijdsalade met tonijn en feta</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame hoofdgerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(360px, 533px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/nasispeciaal.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/nasi.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Nasi Speciaal</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame tussendoortje" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(720px, 534px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/borrelworst.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/borrelworst.jpg" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Borrelworst met abrikozenchutney</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame tussendoortje" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(720px, 534px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/yoghurtbar.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/yoghurtbar.png" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Yoghurtbar met granola</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
                <li class="cbp-item frame voorgerecht" style="width: 350px; transform: translate3d(0px, 531px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper"> <a href="recepten/tomatensoep.php" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/recepten/tomatensoep.PNG" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Snelle Tomatensoep</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /cbp-l-grid-masonry -->
    </div>
    <!-- /box -->
</section>

<!--/Recepten galerij-->


<footer class="footer">
    <img src="images/logo.png" height="58" width="116">
    <a href="#" style="padding-left: 100px; color: black;">Algemene voorwaarden</a>
    <a href="#" style="padding-left: 100px; padding-right: 100px; color: black;">Privacy en Cookies</a>
    &copy; 2019 Tristan de Muijnck
</footer>

<!--Scripts-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.7.0/jquery.lettering.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Can you ping the CDN url from the server? It might be blocked.

Comment: looks like you're loading jquery at least 3 times - that's always going to be a problem - are their any errors in the browser developer console?

Comment: I cleared my code from the multiple jQuery loadings, but I am still having the same problem. Also all the pictures do load but they load like the wrong gallery picture provided in my post. I do not have acces to the server since it is a private server from my school. I do get an error in my browsers console but I get that same error on localhost and it does still work there. It has something to do with dropdown not being a function, but I am not using any dropdown in the gallery part.

Comment: I solved the problem. It works on both localhost and school server now. Thanks everyone for th suggestions. There was a css file who was copied over but ended up being empty. I know really dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since some of the page working i think its issue with images so you can try

1. You are loading more than once jQuery , clear your code and leave only one jQuery
2. As i see some of the images are there so check on server machine if all images exist by typing their path in browser

> www.domain.com/images/sample-image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Removing unnecessary jQuery libraries and rewriting a corrupted css file fixed the problem.